# How do i started ambari hortonworks services?

Tags: hadoop, hortonworks-data-platform, ambari, hortonworks-sandbox

I just installed Hortonwroks Sandbox via virtualbox. And when i started Ambari every services was red like you can see in this [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5nxBu.jpg) . Have i missed something? i'm a beginner in hadoop

Comment: Sandbox comes with the default configuration to start most of the services, make sure you have enough free memory.

Comment: i do have enough free memory

Answer (score 0):

Actually, when we start HDP Sandbox all Services services go into the starting stage except Strome, Atlas, Hbase (This can be checked by Gear Icon on the top right side from there you can check the reason behind of failed Services).

Try to Manually Start services in the following manner

1. Zookeeper
2. HDFS
3. YARN
4. MapReduce
5. Hive

Comment: Nothing happens when I click on the action button and then on start all services. I even tried to start each service alone but still nothing is happening.

Comment: @emeric from the screenshot I can see that you have login to Ambari as **maria_dev** user, If you haven't changed user Settings the default username & password is **raj_ops**. So, login as **raj_ops** and try to do the same thing as I've mentioned in Answer.

Comment: i'm still unable to start any of the services.